# Any way to add another class in here using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, tampermonkey

In this image this is the whole div in the html I wish to have another `<span>`

In this span I want it to be called "Kappers" and in the class I want it to hold the variable called `ExcelDataSheetPrice` is there anyway to add this I have made an attempt but it doesn't seem to work - anyone got any ideas? (currently running script on tampermonkey)

Any help appreciate it thank you

[image: Here is the whole div]

which I would like to add my span underneath the "subContent"

My code

```
    $('.pagination.next').keyup(function(e){
        if (e.keycode == 39)
        e.preventDefault();
       // var t = document.createElement("style");
        //t.type = "text/css",
        //t.innerText = "\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem {\n        height: 39px;\n    }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .listFUTItem .label {\n        font-size: 10px;\n  }\n    .SearchResults.ui-layout-left .auction {\n        margin-top: 0 !important;\n        font-size: 12px;\n        top: 4px;\n    }\n",
        //document.head.appendChild(t)
        const div = $('.column');
        div.append('<span class="Kappers">+ExcelDataSheetPrice+</span>')
        setTimeout(function(){
            getPlayerDataFromSite();
        }, 500);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.pagination.next').keyup(function(e){
    if (e.keycode == 39)
      e.preventDefault();
    const div = $('.column'); // watch out for your spelling error (column)
    div.append('<span class="Kappers">+ExcelDataSheetPrice+</span>');
    // do stuff
});
```

Tips for the future:

Press F12 to open your developer console and try to debug your script by inspecting your code, step-by-step.

Maybe use `console.log()` to find the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this with JavaScript

```
document.querySelector(".pagination .next").onkeyup = () => {
if (e.keycode === 39) {
document.querySelector(".column").innerHTML += '<span class="Kappers">' +ExcelDataSheetPrice+ '</span>';
setTimeout(() => {
getPlayerDataFromSite();
}, 500);
}
});
```

Try Now With This If Got Error Give Me Details